# Cant fill a shape in after effects

Tags: color, shapes, adobe-after-effects, fill

i have this weird problem, that i cant fill my shape in after effects. Does anybody know what do do? 
when i want to change the fill, basicly i see this:

[image: Click to see Screenshot]

When i change the color in the fill setting, nothing happens, there is still no fill attached to the shape.

"Fläche" means fill in german :)

Thank you guys!

Comment: Please post a photo of the object in the "layers" panel like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwyyL.png) so we can see what type of object it is

Answer (score 3):

Expand your shape layer, and next to "Contents" there should be a little triangle button with the word "Add" next to it. Add a "Fill" and now you should be able to change the color.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the question mark box then it should bring up the color picker prompter. From there pick a random color and the fill should work again

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on "Fläche" and select the fill type first.